# Как прослушивать порт 8083 с локально подключенного компьютера через SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-key, ssh-tunnel

У меня есть комп, на котором открыт порт 8083, мне необходимо слушать этот порт  с соседнего компа , который подключен к нему через локальную сеть.

C помощью команды ниже я пробрасывал порт с виртуалки на основной комп. Но не могу понять смысл этой команды. Можно ли привести ее в соответствии к **текущей задаче**?

```
  ssh -L 8083:localhost:8083 -p 13577 kalugin@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Хм. Как это ssh на 127.0.0.1 что-то куда-то пробрасывал?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, честно не знаю как все это работает. Но сейчас интересует первая часть вопроса (

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ssh  -L 8083:127.0.0.1:8083 server-zis-3@192.168.33.182
```

-L - локальная сторона прослушивания

8083 - порт моего компа

127.0.0.1:8083 - localhost на порте 8083 компа к которому я подключаюсь

server-zis-3@192.168.33.182 - ip компа к которому подключаюсь